# Credit Card Requirement Free Trial - User Experience

Tags: user-expectation, ux-field, users, signup-signon, credit-cards

Web based application requires a credit card to signup for a free 30 day trial account for which I have got mixed reviews, because application does not enforce any limit on the usage and companies like AWS already run on the model that requires credit card to signup of free 30 days trial.

What is the right user experience? Is having a credit card a mandatory thing to create a free trial?

Comment: I don't think there is a "right" answer, but for me personally, I usually drop right off as soon as someone asks for a credit card before I can get my "free" trial. Same story when the "free" tier of a service is hidden or really hard to find when I'm signing up.

Comment: I think a lot of it depends on what kind of service you offer. If you don't require a CC for the trial, users can keep making throwaway accounts to use the service for free - something that would be simple and convenient to setup for a service like Netflix.